# Java SQLite not updating with prepared statement

Tags: java, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to update my database with a prepared statement, but it has no effect.

Auto-commit is set to true, but I have also tried to put it to false and commit manually. It makes no difference.

I see no error and at the end of this method. I retrieve the row and it seems it updated but when I retrieve all the rows from the database it is not updated.

```
public void updateEstadoDescargaSerie(Serie serie) {
        String sql = "UPDATE SERIES SET DESCARGA_FINALIZADA = ? WHERE NOMBRE = ?;";

        try (
                Connection c = connectDDBB();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {

            // set the corresponding param
            pstmt.setInt(1, serie.getDescargaFinalizada());
            pstmt.setString(2, serie.getNombre());
            // update 
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT:I am trying to brake the code  into peace.This is the code that I use in this part.I do not see what the problem could be..

```
public class Pruebas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        DDBB ddbb =new DDBB();
        ddbb.connectDDBB();
        ddbb.createTables();

        Serie serie =new Serie();
        serie.setNombre("Dark");
        ddbb.insertDataSerie(serie);

        serie = ddbb.selectSerie(serie.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Serie antes de update "+serie.getNombre()+"/"+serie.getId()+"/"+serie.getDescargaFinalizada());

        serie.setDescargaFinalizada(1);
        ddbb.updateEstadoDescargaSerie(serie);
        serie = ddbb.selectSerie(serie.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Serie después de update "+serie.getNombre()+"/"+serie.getId()+"/"+serie.getDescargaFinalizada()); --> this should be updated but it isn't.
    }
}
class DDBB{
        public void updateEstadoDescargaSerie(Serie serie) {
        String sql = "UPDATE SERIES SET DESCARGA_FINALIZADA = ? WHERE NOMBRE = ?";

        try (
                Connection c = connectDDBB();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {

            // set the corresponding param
            pstmt.setInt(1, serie.getDescargaFinalizada());
            pstmt.setString(2, serie.getNombre());
            // update 
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();

            Serie serie2 = selectSerie(serie.getNombre());
            System.out.println("Serie en principio actualizada " + serie2.getNombre() + " / "+serie2.getId());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public Serie selectSerie(String nombreSerie) {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Serie serie = new Serie();
        try {
            Connection c = connectDDBB();
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SERIES WHERE NOMBRE='" + nombreSerie + "';");

            while (rs.next()) {

                int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                String nombre = rs.getString("NOMBRE");
                String linkSerie = rs.getString("LINK_SERIE");

                serie.setId(id);
                serie.setNombre(nombre);
                serie.setLinkSerie(linkSerie);

                //System.out.println("id = " + id);
                //System.out.println("nombre = " + nombre);
                //System.out.println("linkSerie = " + linkSerie);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return serie;
    }
    public Connection connectDDBB() {
        Connection c = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
            config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:torrenttracker4.db", config.toProperties());
            c.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //System.out.println("Opened TorrentTracker database successfully");
        return c;
    }

    public void createTables() {
        Connection c = connectDDBB();
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            /* Create table series */
            stmt = c.createStatement();

            String sqlSeries = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SERIES "
                    + "(ID INTEGER           PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT                NOT NULL,"
                    + " NOMBRE               TEXT                                     NOT NULL, "
                    + " LINK_SERIE           TEXT                                     ,"
                    + " DESCARGA_FINALIZADA  INTEGER                                  DEFAULT 0);";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sqlSeries);

            stmt.close();

            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //System.out.println("Tables created successfully");
    }

    public void insertDataSerie(Serie serie) {
        Connection c = connectDDBB();
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO SERIES (NOMBRE,LINK_SERIE) "
                    + "VALUES ('" + serie.getNombre() + "','" + serie.getLinkSerie() + "');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
            //c.commit();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //System.out.println("Serie insertada con éxito");
    }
}

class Serie {

    public Serie() {
    }
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String linkSerie;
    private int descargaFinalizada;
    public static int DESCARGA_FINALIZADA = 1;
    public static int DESCARGA_NO_FINALIZADA = 0;

    public Serie(String nombreSerie) {
        this.nombre = nombreSerie;
    }

    public Serie(String nombreSerie, String linkSerie) {
        this.nombre = nombreSerie;
        this.linkSerie = linkSerie;
    }

    public Serie(int id, String nombreSerie, String linkSerie) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombreSerie;
        this.linkSerie = linkSerie;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public int getDescargaFinalizada() {
        return this.descargaFinalizada;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getLinkSerie() {
        return this.linkSerie;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDescargaFinalizada(int estadoDescarga) {
        this.descargaFinalizada = estadoDescarga;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setLinkSerie(String link) {
        this.linkSerie = link;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2
WhenI run the code above the id of the serie gets incremented but the field that I change is not updated. Thats not normal, isn't it?

Comment: You forgot c,commit() in the end

Comment: Have you tried to run the query manually, or rather a SELECT query with the same  WHERE clause to verify there exists a row where `NOMBRE` is equal to what's returned by `serie.getNombre()`?

Comment: I thought that there shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of the `string` but maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: Hello guys thank you for yor answers. I have tried to put the second ? like this '?' but it is taken as a string not as a varible. I know I there is a row with that data inserted because this method executes when the name is selected and the list of names is retrived from the database. I also tried to execute it with and without the semicolon...

Comment: @user1055395 My conection is in auto-commit mode

Comment: Just to confirm - you're not getting into the catch(SQLException) block, right?

Comment: @user1055395 No, and if I save the result of the executeUpdate I get a message saying one row was updated

Comment: You say that you know that the name exists because it was read from the database but have you checked that 1) `serie` is correct so that `serie.getNombre()` returns a name and not empty 2) That no extra character like a space has been added to the name 3) there is some special character in the name ('; etc) that might cause a problem? (I don't think 3) should be an issue when you use setString as you do)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I will explain: a have a list that retrives the tv series from the database, when the user click a name i then retrive the Serie object from the database with all data of that tv show. Then I change a property (descargaFinalizada) and I pass the new object to this method, with which I want to update the data. If in this method I retrive the tv show from the database (after updating) I see the updated field but when I retrive this data from outside the method, the field is not updated... I don't know what is happening..

Comment: Guys, nevermind I found the error. I had a problem with the select method, the update was correct but the select did not include that field....stupid me.. anyway thank you very much!!!